# Multiple echo / print with fixed position and inline block

Tags: php, html, css, formatting, echo

I want to make some formatting within html with css to make my data presentable.

My php code is,

```
echo '<br><div class="items">' . "id" .'</div>';
echo '<div class="colon"> : </div>';
echo '<div class="details">' . "12" . '</div>';
```

My css is,

```
.items,.details,.colon {
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
.colon {
  position: fixed;
  left: 200;
}
.items {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 3px 2px 0 8px;
    width: auto;
    display: block; 
    text-align: right;
    margin : 0 auto;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold; 
}
.details {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: left;
}
```

The output i am getting is,
[image]

And the output i want is,
[image]

Can anybody please suggest ?

Answer (score 0):

Your looking for `display:flex;` "The Flexible Box Layout Module, makes it easier to design flexible responsive layout structure without using float or positioning."

*Source @ https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp*

Html

```
<div class="flex-container">
<div class="item auto">auto</div>
<div class="item initial">initial</div>
<div class="item initial">initial</div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.flex-container{background-color:#f4f7f8;overflow:hidden;display:flex;margin:1em}
.item{margin:1em;padding:.5em;width:110px;min-width:0;background-color:#1b5385;color:#fff;font-family:monospace}
.initial{flex:initial}
.auto{flex:auto}
```

Working codepen version https://codepen.io/amarinediary/pen/VwaVMza

Comment: i tried this with my requirement but i am unable to fix. Please help. I am unable to make 200px on left for colon class. I need to make colons visible on same vertical line.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you problem, if you're not more clear I won't be abble to help

Comment: I have entire array output to visible one below other. So i need the colons to be visible exactly one below other at a fixed pixels from left. And entire line should occupy only half width of window not full. e.g. ...........id : 12.............................................